# How are include_once loops handled in php?

Tags: php, php-5.3, php-5.4

I have 3 different files-

1. **fileMainIncludeEverywhere.php**

   ```
   ...
   include_once('fileMinorInclude.php');
   ?>
   ```
2. **fileMinorInclude.php**

   ```
   ...
   include_once('fileMainIncludeEverywhere.php');
   ...
   ```
3. **fileToRun.php**

   ```
   ...
   include_once('fileMainIncludeEverywhere.php');
   ...
   ```

I have a lot of files like *fileToRun.php*.

Currently I'm not facing any errors in my code, but I want to know if there's any case where this would fail?

Comment: No no errors come. You should try reading the manual before posting on SO - https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php. I think it's pretty clear?

Comment: What happened when you tested it?

Comment: @S.Pinkus I've read the manual, and it is written that if the file has been included, it won't be included again. But in my case, the file hasn't been included even once.

Comment: @symcbean I haven't encountered any errors yet, but I have thousands of files like the 3rd file I've mentioned above with too many different cases. So I need some assurance from experts on it.

Comment: @Rahul "But in my case, the file hasn't been included even once" - Ah. This is why unless you've got a special reason not to you should use `require_once()` instead of `include_once()`.

Comment: @S.Pinkus Actually I'm editing existing code, and I don't want it to fail and throw fatal error if there's some issue with include. I want it to not be included in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think no error in this case. Because `include_once` will only load the file for the first time then upcoming load request will be rejected for the same file.

So from your example:

1. `fileToRun.php` will load `fileMainIncludeEverywhere.php` (first call)
2. `fileMainIncludeEverywhere.php` will load `fileMinorInclude.php` (first call)
3. `fileMinorInclude.php` will call to load `fileMainIncludeEverywhere.php` but it will be rejected as it has been already loaded in first step.

Hope it will help.

Comment: This seems like a good reasoning. Has anyone done this in their codebase?

Answer (score 1):

*[include_once](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php):*

> The include_once statement includes and evaluates the specified file during the execution of the script. This is a behavior similar to the include statement, **with the only difference being that if the code from a file has already been included, it will not be included again**, and include_once returns TRUE. As the name suggests, the file will be included just once.

Here "code from a file" also entails the executed PHP file.

Note it's generally best practice to use `require_once()` instead of `include_once()` unless you've got a specific reason for using include_once() (like say including optional template components). This because require_once()  will terminate ([fail fast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast)) if the required resource is not found, and not finding it normally should be a terminal failure.

Comment: I have a special requirement where I want it not to be included if some error comes (like you said about optional components).